# kotlin soundPoolで複数の音源ファイルを簡潔にロードしたい。

Tags: android, kotlin

下記の記事を参考にして、kotlinでandroidアプリを作成しています。

https://akira-watson.com/android/kotlin/soundpool-play.html

やりたいことは50個程のボタンを作成し、サウンドプールでそれぞれのボタンから違う音を出したいです。
ループ文で書くことができたら簡潔に書くことができると思っているのですが、音源をロードする際に

```
soundOne = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.one, 1)
```

の`R.raw.one`を変数にしてそこに音源のファイル名を代入することは可能でしょうか？

また、ボタンのオンクリックイベントの

```
button1.setOnClickListener
```

の`button1`を変数にしてfor文などで回すことはできますか？

Answer (score 0):

音声ファイルの名前を例えば「sound1.mp3」「sound2.mp3」...「sound50.mp3」という名前にしておいて
以下のようにsoundPool.loadの第二引数になるリソースIDを取得してはどうでしょうか？

```
for (i in 1..50)  {
    val resourceId = this.resources.getIdentifier("sound$i", "raw", this.packageName)

}
```